# Acknowledgement of submission to the Annals of Mathematics

Tags: publications, paper-submission

Does the *Annals of Mathematics* always to reply every submission within a few days? I submitted a few times to them before, and every time I hear back from the  editorial office very soon (within three days). But this time there has been no response to my submission for more than one week.

Is this normal? Or I should inquire about the status of my paper?

Comment: Thanks so much, J. Zimmerman, for polishing my english. I am not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A week is not so different from three days, especially if that week includes the July 4th holiday in the U.S.  If several weeks pass and you still have been given no indication that the paper was received, then it would be worth asking if they got it, but in the meantime I don't think you need to worry.

Comment: Did you look at the OP's questions on math.SE by any chance?  I have to think that if you send too many papers about elementary proofs of special cases of FLT to the Annals of Mathematics, then at some point they *will* stop responding.  I am a bit torn as to whether or not to advise the OP on this.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Hmm, good point (I hadn't looked at them).  I don't know how they would handle it.  I hope they would suggest the papers were inappropriate and ask the author to stop sending them, but perhaps they would expect people to take the hint if their papers were repeatedly rejected without refereeing.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am afraid sending too many elementary proofs of special cases of FLT is not the case, but a reasonable, rational guess from my question asked.

Comment: Moreover, I am a bit torn as to say this: inferring the motivation or background of a post is unsolicited.

Comment: @Brian But it might in fact be relevant here. You say you have submitted to them a few times before, but it is clear from your MSE questions that you are not at the moment producing mathematics of anywhere near the quality they expect at the Annals (being one of the very top journals of mathematics). Thus, it is not out of the question that they have put you on some sort of "ignore" (though I have no idea if this is something they would actually do), and this might explain the lack of a reply.

Comment: Hi Tobias (if I may call you Tobias), thanks for your kind words. You are right.  I can understand the point if asked this way (that to answer the question necessitates more information). It is my fault that I did not specify the expected answers. In regard to this question, experience-sharing is preferred to submission-counseling.